# Meteor: Flexbox CSS works in jsFiddle but not in app

Tags: html, css, meteor, flexbox

I've got this flexbox auto-expanding column CSS working nicely in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/disgr4ce/91yfdb4z/1/

```
.fc {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.fcRow {
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;

    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;

    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.fcColumn {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

    height: 100%;
}

html, body {
    margin:0px;
    height: 100%;
}

#header {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

.clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#chatLog {
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height: 0px;

    padding:10px;
}

#chatFooter {
    height: 40px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #eee;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction:row;
}

.logInput {
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

But it doesn't work on my app, despite being literally the exact same contents of the CSS file.  The markup is the same as well, of course, but uses Meteor's template system with Flow-Layout, which only adds one additional `<div id="__flow-root">` at the top level.  The only thing that contains is `display:block;` and fiddling with that doesn't change anything (for the better).

Is there anything else I can check?  The app version is here: http://campchat.meteor.com/room/9sCa5QfW6eqZmGQxW  As you can see, it does not expand `#chatlog` the way the jsFiddle one does.  What gives?

Answer (score 0):

As is so often the case, the statement of the question led me inexorably to the answer: the culprit was indeed Flow-Layout's `#__flow-root`.  All I had to do was specify `100%` there, and everything's working nicely.  Now if I only understood why exactly ;)

Comment: It's still not perfect, though—the height of `#chatLog` affects the heights of the header and footer; the longer `#chatLog` grows, the shorter the heights of those two divs...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, instead of #__flow-root, I had to set the flex props (display, height, and flex-direction) on #__blaze-root, which was containing the entire document within the body.

If you are using BlazeLayout, you can also change the root to be the body (or other arbitrary element) and have your flex styles applied to that like so:

```
BlazeLayout.setRoot('body');
```